# How do I use an array to create multiple object fields in custom inspector?

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, for-loop, unity-game-engine

```
public override void OnInspectorGUI()
   { 
     for(int i =0; i<numberOfObs; i++)
     {
      spawnObjects [i] = (GameObject)EditorGUILayout.ObjectField (spawnObjects      [i], typeof(GameObject), true);
   if(spawnObjects[i] != null)
      { 
        Debug.Log(spawnObjects[i];
      }
     }

   }
```

While this works to create the empty Object field it does not store the gameobject's that are dragged into it.

I can see the object I dropped in but then it just resets value to null. 
How could I create these fields and have them store data without having to make a bunch of single GameObjects to store the items?

Comment: What is the context of the second code block? Where is it getting its value of `i` ?

Comment: It gets the value of I from the for loop int i =0. It is just an index as used in a for loop to cycle through each gameobject in the array. The array is initialized with numberOfObs which is just an integer before the for loop.

Comment: The second block of code there just lets me see that when I drag a gameobject/prefab into blank object field it does register it as that Item but then reverts back to null before you can see the change which is why i used debug to see if it was actually doing anything.